# In Excel macro, construct and evaluate a worksheet array formula

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I'm working with an array formula:

```
{=MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)),ROW(A:A),0))}
```

The specific formula isn't important. In this case, I know I can get the same result with a regular formula. It's just for illustration.

I would like to construct such an array formula in a macro and substitute whatever column I like, but I haven't found anything describing how to execute an array formula from VBA.

I tried using this, which works for regular formulas,

```
Application.Evaluate("{MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)),ROW(A:A),0))}")
```

and

```
Application.Evaluate("{=MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)),ROW(A:A),0))}")
```

but got an error (13-Type mismatch).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the curly brackets from the formula.

```
Application.Evaluate("=MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)),ROW(A:A),0))")
```

Comment: My bad. There was already an answer (see edit to my question above).